# Apply function to function (hard to explain)

Tags: javascript

First off i'd like to apologize for the noobish question.

Please take a look at the following code:

```
var dt = new Date(t*1000);
var m = "0" + dt.getMinutes();
```

When outputted, it can give us one of the following results, depending of the `t` variable (aka unix time):

```
m = 054 // 54 minutes
m = 03 // 3 minutes
```

As you can see, if theres too many minutes, the formatting becomes broken. To fix this, we must call a function to only keep the two last characters. To do this, we'll use the following code:

```
var m = "0" + dt.getMinutes();
m = m.substr(-2);
```

Which can output:

```
m = 54 // 54 minutes
m = 3  // 03 minutes
```

Good! We fixed the problem, right? Well, I think that setting the variable two times in a row is stupid. I tried:

```
var m = "0" + dt.getMinutes().substr(-2);
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: dt.getMinutes(...).substr is not a function
```

Is there a one liner way to do this?

Comment: What im trying to do here is `m = m.functionOne().FunctionTwo();`

Comment: You should learn how to get to the heart of a problem, and actually ask about that.  You don't need to know how to call two functions in a row - you might need that later but that's irrelevant for this one.  Why didn't you simply ask the more basic question 'how do I format a number with a leading zero?' (which is already answered here too)

Comment: `dt.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')`

Comment: I know how to format a number with a leading zero. I wanted to know how to make it a one-liner, without having to set the variable two times. The answers learn'd me here that I must convert my function's output to a string before I can do string-related stuff to my variables (like only keeping the two last characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Date.getMinutes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes) returns an integer, not a string, so you can't call `substr` on it. But by adding parentheses around the `"0" + dt.getMinutes()` expression, you get a string value and you can call `substr`:

```js
var dt = new Date();
var m = ("0" + dt.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
console.log(m);
```